# LUA_INIT environment variable not working

Tags: lua

I'm quite new to the lua language and I'm trying different things. The [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lua) said before the interpreter start, it will looks for the environment variable `LUA_INIT` and if it has the form of `@filename`, the interpreter will run the file `filename` first.

I'm using ubuntu, after I tried to define the `LUA_INIT` variable as `@/home/tontyoutoure/lua/lua_init.lua`, in which I write a simple function, which returns the factorial of a natural number:

```
function fact(n)
    if n == 0 then
        return 1
    else
        return n*fact(n-1)
    end
end
```

I checked the variable, and it seems alright:

```
$ echo $LUA_INIT
@/home/tontyoutoure/lua/lua_init.lua
```

I suppose the interpreter should then load the function `fact` first, but when I start the interpreter and make a simple test:

```
$ lua
> = fact(5)
stdin:1: attempt to call global 'fact' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

It seems to me that the interpreter did not load the file.
So which part did I get wrong?

Comment: Did you create the variable in environment?  `LUA_INIT=xxxxx`  is insufficient - you need `export`.  Otherwise it is local to the shell

Comment: You may check the variable by typing `=os.getenv'LUA_INIT'` in Lua REPL.

Comment: @mksteve Thanks for your answer, problem solved.